# Can't see/connect to home network (but can see other networks && other devices can connect to networ) - (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-connection

Windows 10 can't see my SSID ("House Wifi") but can see others (many many others). Additionally, my linux laptop and my smartphone and ostensibly my roommate's devices (no complaints yet) can see my "House Wifi" SSID. Why is my windows system blind to this one and only this one?

More details: I just installed a new modem from xfinity. I did this because I was due for an upgrade, and because I had a connection problem earlier in the day. I wasn't going to replace anything that wasn't broken, but since the network went down, I thought, ok let's upgrade. The network earlier was fixed with a simple windows 10 restart. I don't know what the issue was. I tried a lot of things but just restarting it fixed it. Then it worked all afternoon till 5 and then I went and got my new modem.

After installing the new modem, all other devices worked instantaneously. This is where it gets interesting. At first Windows 10 could see my renewed SSID "House Wifi" and it would try to connect and would say it failed. I can't remember the specific message. There was an exception to this though. If I disabled wifi altogether or put on airplane mode and took off, and connected, then it would say connected, secure. However, when I actually tried to access a website, it would regress to staying 'connecting' and I would never be able to make a connection with the wifi and the new modem.

In this time I restarted the computer a lot, restarted the modem, and nothing helped. I ran the diagnostic and got a message: "Wireless association failed because Windows did not receive any response from the wireless router". I did some searching, tried a few things. I reset winsock and resinstalled my Intel(R) Dual Band WirelessAC7265 device. That seemed to go successfully, but it didn't fix the problem. I connected through an ethernet cable before I did this which is what I'm on now. That has disconnected before on its own so I'm worried about relying on that alone, but also the name of it is XFSETUP01-F2 even though set up of the modem should be complete.

Anyway after reinstalling the drivers and winsock and multiple restarts, I now no longer see my SSID "House Wifi" but I still see a lot of other SSIDs and I still see "House Wifi" strong signal on other devices. I don't know why I can only not see this one network on this one machine.

My windows 10 is up to date.

I have a VPN but that should not affect anything especially before I'm connected to anything. I have VirtualBox but I don't use it much. I'm just trying to think of anything that could be the issue. I have been using the PC in the same location with the same company with no problem for 4 years. I was on the phone with them for 2 hours and they couldn't figure it out. Asus also wouldn't help me for free.

I'm very curious and motivated to get this resolved. Tomorrow I will try take it to a local coffeeshop to see if it connects to anything whatsoever. If so then it seems like it is modem compatibility, but I don't know why that would be the case. Doesn't it go through Windows 10 and stay backwards compatible? If that's the case, I am up to date.

It's a very specific network that is invisible, although I'm not sure I can connect to the other ones yet. (I don't have my neighbors' passwords).

I would very much appreciate any leads. It's probably something little and insignificant. I hope I've given you enough clues. Appreciation.

Edit: I can't rollback drivers- at least not through the standard "Device Manager" way. That option is grayed out.

I checked out my ROG GL552VW firmware version. It says it's version 3.0 and the current version per the Asus site is 303. So perhaps I'm behind but it updated in July 2019 and my machine has worked good since then. I really wish I could roll back drivers or see the history (as some update a few years ago broke my internal webcam so I got a USB external webcam) but this info is not available to me in a way I know how to access. [btw my computer is great and fun for most uses and I don't do anything crazy with it. I do use a VPN and virtual box (which I disabled earlier to avoid potential conflicts) but I'm not even really a gamer. That said, I'm wondering if Asus/Rog line is known for problems of these types, related to drivers, devices and such]

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, though I don't know exactly why it started to work now. 2 things I did in the last session (cycle between reboots). I did try other things since this post but I am pretty sure it has to be one of these two or else just something completely in the background of the system and services that would have eventually worked anyways, and I don't think it's that. I think the solution was #2 but it's a guess.

#1 from [this guidance here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-wi-fi-connection-issues-in-windows-9424a1f7-6a3b-65a6-4d78-7f07eee84d2c) I did

```
Type netsh int ip reset and select Enter.

Type ipconfig /release and select Enter.

Type ipconfig /renew and select Enter.

Type ipconfig /flushdns and select Enter.
```

Reason I don't think it was this was because I did the first two commands above and it didn't fix it. Additionally, it said as before that it required a restart and I hadn't gotten to that point before I tried #2. It didn't fix it by itself without the restart either, but I did do these commands in this reboot cycle. I still haven't restarted btw and it works.

20 minutes after doing the above, after reading up on intel 7265 I find [this form thread](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/intel-wireless-ac-7265-refuses-to-connect-to-wifi.248829/) and specifically the post near the bottom re: Bluetooth

#2 I turned off Bluetooth- nothing fancy, just toggling it off in the settings, and then I check my list of networks and I know right away it worked because I see the two XFINITY networks that I stopped seeing before- at full signal, and then I see my own "House Wifi". I connect to my own, and it connects securely. I unplug ethernet and I'm still connected. Woo hoo. I don't know what the issue was. I wasn't even using Bluetooth- not even passively with any devices that I'm aware of.  I don't use it much on this machine. I usually avoid fix or debug instructions referring to it as I think it has nothing to do with wifi but maybe they interact and create some kind of interference. Maybe it was showing all the networks that were 2.4 gHz and not showing or connecting to all the 5gHz.

I didn't get any conclusive answers but I learned some things, updated my BIOS from an older version successfully, got an updated router in the process, etc

I'm not sure if Bluetooth and WiFi might be related or commonly interfere with each other. Are they running on the same network adaptor card? I like to know how things work on the lowest level, the physical level, so if they are running on the same card, it's easy to see how they might be interfering or hogging some channel or port. I'm just naively speculating about what could be going on but I like using practical examples as a springboard to learning more theory, as opposed to vice versa.